# How can I access the canvas element without an id?

Tags: javascript, dom, css-selectors, frontend, casperjs

Using CasperJs, I'm trying to do some testing on canvas, by grabbing it and using `canvas.toDataURL();`. However, the canvas does not have an id, the code looks something like this:

```
<div id= 'derp' ...>
<canvas ...> </canvas>
</div>
```

Can I still get the canvas using something like

```
var canvas = document.getElementById(????);
```

or is there a better way of grabbing the canvas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use CSS selectors:

```
document.querySelector('#derp canvas')
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also list all the canvas with this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')
```